# PHPStorm: Unresolved variable/type; how to resolve?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

Where should I find or how to create a library to remove the warnings about unresolved variables/types?

Examples:

```
var fs=window.webkitRequestFileSystem; //Unresolved variable webkitRequestFileSystem

var audio=new Audio(); //Unresolved type Audio
```

Comment: What version of PHPStorm are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Download the [Closure Compiler](http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip).

Unpack the `.js` files from `externs.zip`, there will be `fileapi.js` file, add this file to the JavaScript libraries in PhpStorm to get the code completion and resolution.

You may want to create a library with all these `.js` files in case you are using other APIs.

Comment: This worked for me. I was developing something for Google Cast and was using the `chrome` object so I created a library using `chrome.js` from `externs.zip`.

Answer (score -2):

Just a ONE-LINE solution

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
```